# hibernate gen table error org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build()" because "entityManagerFactoryBuilder" is null

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I fail to generate table from entity in eclipse with error org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build()" because "entityManagerFactoryBuilder" is null
I have three hibernate classes :

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
abstract public class GameBean implements Serializable  {       
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8690022943103849312L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    protected GameBean(){
    }
} 

@Entity
@Table(name="CheckersGame")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class CheckersGameBean extends GameBean{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6448336204266253962L;

    
    protected CheckersGameBean(){
        super();            
    }       
}
@Entity
@Table(name="ChessGame")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class ChessGameBean extends GameBean {   
    
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3921250444757041509L;  

    protected ChessGameBean(){      
        super();            
    }   
}
```

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
byte-buddy-1.10.10.jar
classmate-1.5.1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
commons-lang.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
dom4j-2.1.3.jar
ezmorph.jar
FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar
hibernate-envers-5.4.15.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpamodelgen-5.4.15.Final.jar
istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar
jandex-2.1.3.Final.jar
javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar
javax.activation_1.1.0.v201211130549.jar
javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar
javax.xml_1.3.4.v201005080400.jar
javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201105210648.jar
jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar
json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar
log4j.properties
mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar
stax-ex-1.8.jar
txw2-2.3.1.jar
```

persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="JPAUNIT-BOARDGAMES" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider         
        <class>com.strategisina.ontheboard.bean.CheckersGameBean</class>        
        <class>com.strategisina.ontheboard.bean.ChessGameBean</class>       
        <class>com.strategisina.ontheboard.bean.GameBean</class>        
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>   
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASE"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="USER"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="PASSWORD"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

When I try to generate the tables with the JPA Tool/Generate Tables from Entries, the above error appears and no generation is done.
I would be really cool to get help with that, its a little time I'm on it !

Answer (score 0):

I succeed in making it work. I used in Console Configuration a Annotation (Jdk 1.5+) type and a Hibernate Version 4.3. And then I succeeded in generating the tables with this console configuration. As I didn't understand what was wrong, I can't explain the solution. It works as well with JPA, with persistence.xml as follows

````
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="JPAUNIT" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
         <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>```
````